How to keep the button over the other elements even if it is disabled in Jetpack Compose?
I have a screen where I display a list of items:
Scaffold(
    content = {
      //List of items
    },
    floatingActionButton = {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                if (buttonEnabled) {
                    buttonEnabled = false
                    //Add item
                }
            },
            enabled = buttonEnabled
        ){
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
)

I have used a Button instead of a FloatingActionButton. The Button is displayed in the bottom right corner. Each row has a trash bin at the end of each row, which means that the button is displayed on top of the last trash bin:

When I click the button, the button is disabled for a few moments, as long as it takes for the operation to complete, and then it is again enabled. The problem is that while the button is disabled, it looks like this:

As soon as the operation completes, the button is displayed correctly again. How can I keep the button over the other views even if it is disabled?
P.S. I don't want to use a FloatingActionButton because has many constraints. Thanks
